# Delphi 10.1 Berlin idHTTP / IPv6 / iOS / Socket Error #51 Network is unreachable

Tags: ios, delphi, https, ipv6

We cannot pass the application test. At Apple's request, we added our static IPv6 address to our server. With our application, everything works out for us, but were refused again. The problem remains the same.

They get an error: `Socket Error #51 Network is unreachable.`

It's unclear why they cannot connect to our server during the test?

What are we doing wrong? do we need to support IPv4 and IPv6 ?

We use the following components on

**Client:**

1. idHTTP
2. IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

**Server:**

1. IdHTTPServer
2. IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL

The server has a static IPv6 address, and it is available.

We process the connection in the following manner:

```
try 
 IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.IPVersion := Id_IPv6; 
 answerBuff := idHTTP1.Post('https://[xxxx:a0e0:bad:bad::53]:8001/', tmpPostRequestData); 
except 
 IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
 answerBuff := idHTTP1.Post('https://xx.85.157.25:8001', tmpPostRequestData); 
end;
```

We do not use a domain name, only direct addresses.
Server IPv6 address is available. Please help someone.

Forgive our English.

Comment: You should be setting `TIdHTTP`'s own `IPVersion` property instead of the `SSLIOHandler`'s property. If at all, since `TIdHTTP` automatically determines IP version from the URL passed in. You shouldn't need to specify `IPVersion` manually when using IP addresses, only when using hostnames (if not wrapped in brackets). Did you verify the device is connected to an IPv6 network when requesting an IPv6 address? Have you done any local testing, per Apple's guidelines, before submitting your app to the store?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thank you very much Remy.
Here is what an employee of Apple writes to us:

Comment: @RemyLebeau
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone 6s running iOS 11.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
---
Remy, we have a test application that will use the following code:
> IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
answerBuff := idHTTP1.Post('https://[2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::53]:8001/', tmpPostRequestData);

The application works fine, there is a connection. But if we send a version with the same code for Apple, then for some reason they can not connect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
We sent the test application to our friends in Germany, they receive the same error as Apple.

I have an assumption that the matter is that our server is in Russia and the answer to them may take too long, so the error is:

Windows App: Socket Error # 10051 Network is unreachable.
iOS App: Socket Error #51 Network is unreachable.

We really need help.

Comment: "*We discovered one or more bugs in your app*" - very unhelpful if they don't tell you what the bugs actually are. "*our friends in Germany, they receive the same error as Apple*" - well, then you have a test environment outside of Apple with which to debug your code, packet sniff network traffic, do whatever you need to do to track down the problem. You have already seen the app working, so it is likely an environmental issue instead of a coding issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ty Remy, That's right, that's exactly what we're going to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There are suggestions why the application might not work for Apple?

Answer (score 1):

We have solution.

Our problems with Wi-Fi connection resolved.

> 1. The roots of the problem were growing due to the use of SSL. Please note that the receiving side (server) must listen to your secure traffic on port 443. Accordingly, the client must also send traffic to this port, or do not specify the port in the URL.
> 2. The second part of the problem was that after a lot of failure using the domain name, I despaired and refused to use the domain name to send requests, and tried to use direct IPv4, IPv6 address. It was a wrong decision. The problem is that SSL certificates are issued to the name of my domain, but not to the addresses of the tied servers.The firewall was cursing and did not let us go any further. Just use your domain name, and use correct ports.

Don't forgot include AAAA ns records in your donaim name. Sry our eng.

Best regards Sergey.